Are primitive ideals left maximal in a non-commutative ring?
Let $\mathcal{R}$ ring and $I \subset \mathcal{R} $. $I$ is called a primitive ideal of $\mathcal{R}$ if it is a left ideal and $\exists \, M$ simple left $\mathcal{R}- $module such that $Ann(M)=I$. If R is commutative, then I is maximal as a left ideal and I was trying to figure out whether the same holds in the non-commutative case. I do not think that this is true, but I haven't managed to find a counterexample, so I would really appreciate it if someone could find a counterexample or prove the statement.

Let $k$ be a field (or more generally: a division ring). It is well known that $k^n$ is simple over $M_n(k)$ ring for any $n$.
You can verify that $Ann(k^n)=0$ over $M_n(k)$. And so $0$ is primitive, but of course $0$ ideal is not maximal in $M_n(k)$ for $n>1$.
